# Is there a way to hidden ListBoxItem by Visibility property of it's child

Tags: c#, wpf

there is a very simple WPF UI,no behind code, the part of xaml is below:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lst" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource YDTTextColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                    **<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding }" />** 
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource YDTBorderColor}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Margin="0,6" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                CornerRadius="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                        TargetName="Bd"
                                        Value="{StaticResource YDTMainBackColor}"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBox.Items>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Tag="NegotiateSale" Height="Auto" 
                                Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Static bo:SysParameter.MDPOS0075}, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
                        <Image Source="../../Images/NegotiateSale.png" Height="32" Margin="30,0,14,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="someText"/>
                </StackPanel>
...
```

i hope when the StackPanel Collapsed,the ListBoxItem's BorderThickness is 0. because when the StackPanel Collapsed,the border line of the item we can see it.
how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, just bind Visibility in ItemContainerStyle to the content visibility property, eg.:

```
 <ListBox
        x:Name="lst"
        Grid.Row="0"
        BorderThickness="0"
        FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
        >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Visibility, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Border
                                BorderBrush="Green"
                                BorderThickness="2"
                                >
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <StackPanel
                Width="50"
                Height="50"
                Background="Red"
                Visibility="Collapsed"
                >
                <Image
                    Height="32"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel
                Width="50"
                Height="50"
                Background="Yellow"
                Visibility="Visible"
                >
                <Image
                    Height="32"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
```

As you can see in the attached picture the yellow square is visible but red is not
[image]